# Замедление времени

Tags: этимология

Рылся в словаре и, глядя на английское соответствие "time dilation", решил, что "dilation" переводится как "замедление". Однако не тут-то было. В английском словаре никакого замедления не наблюдается. Dilation переводится как "расширение". Есть ещё похожее слово "dilatation" с тем же значением. Почему у нас "замедление", в то время как у них (во всём нормальном мире) "расширение"?

Comment: Вы, видимо, уверены, что это проблема русского языка, а не нормального мира.

Comment: @shampar Я рассуждаю в навязанной нам демократами парадигме. С 1991-го года мы живём в т.н. `новом мире`. В рамках заданного нам дискуса мы, немытая россия, возвращаемся на столбовую дорогу цивилизации и должны смотреть в зубы "цивилизованному сообществу", считая его правым во всех расхождениях. Как бы там ни было, интересно узнать откуда отличия. Чтобы знать кто прав а кто нет, надо разобраться откуда оно повелось, что люди хотели вложить в понятия, выбрав такие термины.

Comment: "(во всём нормальном мире) расширение?"- вы,наверное, имели в виду замедление?

Comment: В "Универсальным русско-английском словаре" переводится как ***расширение времени***.

Comment: Вы пишете:  "Почему у нас ***расширение*** когда у них (во всём нормальном мире) ***расширение***? У кого замедление, а у кого расширение? "Ваш вопрос в чем?

Comment: Пока Вы будете писать "Россия" со строчной буквы, вас не то что на столбовую не пустят, вас и с проселочной выгонят. И потом, если это вам демократы навязали путь в цивилизованное общество, то радоваться надо, что и тут у русских - не как у людей.  )))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы осилите хотя бы основы релятивистской теории, то вопрос отпадет сам собой. ***Dilation*** - только в одном из значений "расширение"; второе, более актуальное здесь - ***растяжение***. Время ***тянется***, т. е. ***замедляется***. Видимо, именно такая аналогия взяла верх.

В Теории же относительности под ним понимают эффект, для которого трудно подобрать бытовой термин. Он означает появление разницы в показаниях часов наблюдателей, движущихся относительно друг друга, при сведении их в одну точку (подробности позвольте оставить для другой целевой аудитории). Это и не расширение, и не замедление, это вообще черт знает что в классической картине мира. Возможно "задержка" - более точное соответствие. Или еще что-то, но прижилось именно "замедление".

"Почему оно" - это уже вопрос некорректный, ибо Божьим промыслом сие было уготовано. Как, впрочем, и 99% вопросов, начинающихся с "почему", если только спрашивающий не ожидает раскрытия реальной причинно-следственной связи.

Answer (score 1):

Dilation (dilatation) - *расширение временного интервала*. Логично предположить, что времени требуется больше, отсюда и ваше *замедление*.

Comment: Это конечно, так, но контекста совершенно не учитывает.